Smoothly show resizing of DataGridView
When resizing columns/rows, the dgv doesn't visually update until you finish. It also doesn't show the regular "resizing bar" across the cells to show where it will end up.

Is there a way to make the row/column update live with moving the mouse instead of just when its finished?

By creating a Custom Control (Windows Forms) that inherits from DataGridView, the problem is almost solved.
By the following class, the movement of the cell divider for the grid at the time of resizing with the mouse can be done smoothly and continuously for both columns and rows.
DataGridView_WithSmoothResizing.cs:
public partial class DataGridView_WithSmoothResizing : DataGridView
{
    public DataGridView_WithSmoothResizing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RowHeadersVisible = true;
        ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
        RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
    }

    public const int ROW_HEADERS_COLUMN_INDEX = -1;
    public const int INVALID_COLUMN_INDEX = -2;

    public const int COLUMNS_ROW_INDEX = -1;
    public const int INVALID_ROW_INDEX = -2;

    private int f_Base_X = 0;
    private int f_Base_Y = 0;
    private bool f_IsColumnResizing = false;
    private bool f_IsRowResizing = false;
    private int f_Resizing_Column_Index = INVALID_COLUMN_INDEX;
    private int f_Resizing_Row_Index = INVALID_ROW_INDEX;
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseLeftClick(e))
        {
            ReserveMouseLocation(e);
            if (IsSetResizingColumnCursor)
                ReserveResizingColumnIndex(e.X);
            else if (IsSetResizingRowCursor)
                ReserveResizingRowIndex(e.Y);
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ResetResizingColumnIndex();
        ResetResizingRowIndex();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseLeftClick(e))
        {
            if (f_IsColumnResizing)
            {
                var DeltaX = e.X - f_Base_X;
                if (DeltaX != 0)
                    ResizeColumn(f_Resizing_Column_Index, DeltaX);
            }
            else if (f_IsRowResizing)
            {
                var DeltaY = e.Y - f_Base_Y;
                if (DeltaY != 0)
                    ResizeRow(f_Resizing_Row_Index, DeltaY);
            }
        }
        ReserveMouseLocation(e);
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
    protected int GetColumnIndex(int X)
    {
        if (IsSetResizingColumnCursor)
        {
            var Relative_X = X - Left;
            for (int ColumnIndex = 0; ColumnIndex < Columns.Count; ColumnIndex++)
            {
                var IsFirstColumn = (ColumnIndex == 0);
                var IsLastColumn = (ColumnIndex == Columns.Count - 1);
                var NextColumnIndex = ColumnIndex + 1;
                var ThisColumnArea = GetColumnArea(ColumnIndex);
                var NextColumnArea = IsLastColumn ? ThisColumnArea : GetColumnArea(NextColumnIndex);
                if (IsFirstColumn && (Relative_X < RowHeadersWidth))
                    return ROW_HEADERS_COLUMN_INDEX;
                if (IsInsideColumnArea(Relative_X, ThisColumnArea, NextColumnArea))
                    return ColumnIndex;
            }
        }
        return INVALID_COLUMN_INDEX;
    }
    protected int GetRowIndex(int Y)
    {
        if (IsSetResizingRowCursor)
        {
            var Relative_Y = Y; // "Y" is relative, so the "Top" value does not need to be subtracted from "Y".
            for (int RowIndex = 0; RowIndex < Rows.Count; RowIndex++)
            {
                var IsFirstRow = (RowIndex == 0);
                var IsLastRow = (RowIndex == Rows.Count - 1); // Including new empty row
                var NextRowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
                var ThisRowArea = GetRowArea(RowIndex);
                var NextRowArea = IsLastRow ? ThisRowArea : GetRowArea(NextRowIndex);
                if (IsFirstRow && IsInsideRowAreaForColumnsHeader(Relative_Y, ThisRowArea))
                    return COLUMNS_ROW_INDEX;
                if (IsInsideRowAreaForData(Relative_Y, ThisRowArea, NextRowArea))
                    return RowIndex;
            }
        }
        return INVALID_ROW_INDEX;
    }
    private void ResizeColumn(int ColumnIndex, int DeltaX)
    {
        if (ColumnIndex == ROW_HEADERS_COLUMN_INDEX)
        {
            // Row Headers Resizing                           
            if (RowHeadersWidth + DeltaX > 5)
                RowHeadersWidth += DeltaX;
        }
        else if ((ColumnIndex > INVALID_COLUMN_INDEX) && (ColumnIndex < Columns.Count))
            Columns[ColumnIndex].Width += DeltaX;
    }
    private void ResizeRow(int RowIndex, int DeltaY)
    {
        if (RowIndex == COLUMNS_ROW_INDEX)
        {
            // Columns Row Resizing                           
            if (ColumnHeadersHeight + DeltaY > 5)
                ColumnHeadersHeight += DeltaY;
        }
        else if ((RowIndex > INVALID_ROW_INDEX) && (RowIndex < Rows.Count))
            Rows[RowIndex].Height += DeltaY;
    }
    private bool IsMouseLeftClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        return (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left);
    }
    private void ReserveMouseLocation(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        f_Base_X = e.X;
        f_Base_Y = e.Y;
    }
    private void ReserveResizingColumnIndex(int X)
    {
        f_IsColumnResizing = true;
        f_Resizing_Column_Index = GetColumnIndex(X);
    }
    private void ReserveResizingRowIndex(int Y)
    {
        f_IsRowResizing = true;
        f_Resizing_Row_Index = GetRowIndex(Y);
    }
    private void ResetResizingColumnIndex()
    {
        f_IsColumnResizing = false;
        f_Resizing_Column_Index = INVALID_COLUMN_INDEX;
    }
    private void ResetResizingRowIndex()
    {
        f_IsRowResizing = false;
        f_Resizing_Row_Index = INVALID_ROW_INDEX;
    }
    public bool IsSetResizingColumnCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Cursor == Cursors.SizeWE);
        }
    }
    public bool IsSetResizingRowCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Cursor == Cursors.SizeNS);
        }
    }
    private Rectangle GetColumnArea(int ColumnIndex)
    {
        return GetCellDisplayRectangle(ColumnIndex, 0, false);
    }
    private Rectangle GetRowArea(int RowIndex)
    {
        return GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, RowIndex, false);
    }
    private bool IsInsideColumnArea(int X, Rectangle ThisColumnRect, Rectangle NextColumnRect)
    {
        return (X > ThisColumnRect.X) && (X < (ThisColumnRect.X + ThisColumnRect.Width + NextColumnRect.Width / 2));
    }
    private bool IsInsideRowAreaForData(int Y, Rectangle ThisRowRect, Rectangle NextRowRect)
    {
        return (Y > ThisRowRect.Y) && (Y < (ThisRowRect.Y + ThisRowRect.Height + NextRowRect.Height / 2));
    }
    private bool IsInsideRowAreaForColumnsHeader(int Y, Rectangle ThisRowRect)
    {
        return (Y < ColumnHeadersHeight + ThisRowRect.Height / 4);
    }
}

